# R script merge 2 rows

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, row

I have one data frame like:

```
       a   b      c       d       e    f   g  
 1     Car 10/02  01/02   30/02   14   1   NA
 2     Car 10/02  07/02   20/02    0   NA   7
```

I want to get :

```
       a   b      c       d       e    f   g  
 1     Car 10/02  01/02   20/02   14   1   7
```

Like a group by (a,b) , select the min Date for c and d, select the max for e and select the non-null for f and g

How can I solve it in R ?

Comment: Please share the data using `dput` and the logic

Comment: I want to group by (a,b) select the Date min on c and on d select the max number on e select the not null on f and g

Comment: whats the pattern. in col d you take the second value .  in col c you take the first row

Comment: I take the min Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` we can `group_by` `a` and `b`, convert `c` and `d` to actual dates using `dmy` from `lubridate` and select the minimum date, select `max`imum value of `e` and non-NA value of `f` and `g`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(a, b) %>%
  summarise(c = c[which.min(dmy(paste0(c, "/19")))], 
             d = d[which.min(dmy(paste0(d, "/19")))], 
             e = max(e), 
             f = f[!is.na(f)], 
             g = g[!is.na(g)])

#   a     b     c     d         e     f     g
#  <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>   <dbl> <int> <int>
#1 Car   10/02 01/02 20/02    14     1     7
```

As shown in the example, I am assuming you would have only one non-NA value for `f` and `g` if you have more than one then use `which.max` to select the first non-NA value from those columns.

Answer (score 0):

using data.table.  I had to change one of your dates because there is no feb 30th

```
    x <-  data.frame( 
     a= c( "Car","Car"), b=c("10/20","10/20"), c=c("01/02","07/02"),d=c("28/02","20/02"), e=c(14,0), f=c(1, NA), g=c(NA,7)) 

     library( data.table) # you may need to install
     x <- data.table( x )

#convert to dates
     x$c <- as.Date(x$c, "%d/%m")
     x$d <- as.Date(x$d, "%d/%m")

# group as you specfied
     x[ ,

         .(
             c = min( c ),
             d = min( d ),
             e = max( e ),
             f= max( f , na.rm=T),
             g= max( g , na.rm=T)
         ) ,

     by= c( "a","b")
     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use library dplyr, let's say your dataframe is df. First thing is replace NA by 0

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0 # you can now directly take sum of f and g column in group by
library(dplyr)
df_1 <- df %>% group_by(a,b) %>% summarise(c = min(c),d = min(d),e = max(e),f = sum(f),g = sum(g))
```

Comment: `min` would not work for dates. (column `c` and `d`). Here it works because `min(c("01", "07"))` gives you "01" but it would give you unexpected results for `min(c("11", "7"))`. You need to convert it to date first to use `min`, `max` functions.